# Trying to update a Samsung store app - getting error "The signing key is invalid. Please check the signing key of the binary"

Tags: android, coronasdk, keystore, signing

We are building an update Android apk using Corona SDK - with the Target App Store set to "Samsung".

We are definitely using the same keystore file that we used to sign the original build. I've used it plenty of times, and it's the only one I have for this app so it's definitely the right one. When uploading updates to Google Play it has worked fine, it's just not working on the Samsung store for some reason

We keep getting this error message:

"The signing key is invalid. Please check the signing key of the binary"

I can only presume this refers to the keystore used to sign the application, searching for the problem didn't turn up much, other that someone who had asked the same question on the samsung forums and never got a reply.

Is there something else we could have missed?

Comment: Make sure you use the same versions of JDK, SSL and the correct Key password when signing the App

Comment: Hmmm, JDK could be the issue, everything else is the same. I'll try that out and then update this post.

Comment: Make sure you use the Keytool of the original JDK

Comment: Made no difference, still getting the same error unfortunately.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turned out that the error was not at our end, it was being caused be a fault on the store itself.
We had to delete the app and upload it again as a new application, at Samsung's suggestion.