# Update error on samsung store: the signing key is invalid

Tags: code-signing, samsung-mobile

since a few weeks a error showed up while trying to update my app on the samsung store.

The error message is this: 
The signing key is invalid. Please check the signing key of the binary.

Neither the links i googled for could help. 
(this one included: [Trying to update a Samsung store app - getting error "The signing key is invalid. Please check the signing key of the binary"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144436/trying-to-update-a-samsung-store-app-getting-error-the-signing-key-is-invalid))

The signing is correct. The same app updates fine on google play or amazon.
Our developer couldn't find any suspicious line of code. We have not changed anything on how we build and upload the app.

How can this problem be resolved?